# Filter values from database query

Tags: java, mysql, database, forms

I have the following filter which i use to get values from database: [image]

On submitting the form, i execute the following query:

```
  SELECT id, Month, Year, SUM(3R02) AS 3R02, SUM(3R05) AS 3R05 
    FROM varcosts 
   WHERE (    Month = 03 
          AND Month = 02 
          AND Year = 2013) 
      OR (    Month = 03 
          AND Month = 02 
          AND Year = 2014) 
GROUP BY Year, Month
```

Since I use servlet to execute the query, it becomes cumbersome to implement this query. Just as a question, is there an easier way to write this query? I am looking for a way in which i can include all the months selected by the user in checkbox without repeating `AND Month = ..` for each month. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: You can use the MySQL `BETWEEN` clause for months and/or years: `WHERE Month BETWEEN 'X' AND 'Y' `.

Comment: and what if user selects random months? will that work?

Comment: ...then provide those random months as parameters in your query, but first filter them (in order to avoid SQL injection), or use prepared SQL statements.

Comment: `Month = 03 AND Month = 02` is contradictory so the result set is always empty.

Comment: No, it is not. Because i'm selecting multiple months. Its checkboxes not select boxes.

Comment: It is. Nevertheless where your values come from `Month = 03 AND Month = 02` is contradictory. The query you posted is just not representing what you're intended to query. Your intention was to query `Month = 02 OR Month = 03` which is the same as `Month in (02, 03)`.

Comment: IF You replace AND by OR, this means you are selecting ANY of the following months and not ALL. And i wanted to get all months. I'm sorry but i came here after trying and testing.

Comment: You're wrong. There will be no row matching `Month = 02 AND Month = 03` at the same time. This is mathematically impossible. It is contradictory and therefore the resultset MUST always be empty. That the `in-clause` works for you just shows that you mean `or` which makes sense, because you want to get all rows where the month is one of the selected.

Comment: I want them in different rows ofcourse. How can i have both in the same row.

Comment: @IbrahimNadir Exactly, that's the point why it's contradictory what you've written. It's impossible ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with an `IN` statement:

```
  SELECT id, Month, Year, SUM(3R02) AS 3R02, SUM(3R05) AS 3R05 
    FROM varcosts 
   WHERE (    Month IN(03,02)   
          AND Year = 2013) 
      OR (    Month IN (02,03)
          AND Year = 2014) 
GROUP BY Year, Month
```

Comment: Not exactly what i wished for but much more convince i guess. Thanks i'll take that as an answer. Basically, i thought if there is a way around the `AND` and `OR` for each year. Instead write months just once and it will search among all the months for all the years selected.

Comment: @IbrahimNadir ... use the same IN-Clauses for years like this `... WHERE Month in (03, 02) AND Year in (2013, 2014) and RESP in (...)` btw: `02` as literal seem odd to me. Either it should be `'02'` for char columns or just `2` for number columns. Same for `03` as literal.

Comment: Happy to have helped you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IN clause to avoid repeating OR statements: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Plus shouldn't your query be more like:

```
WHERE ((Month = 03 OR Month = 02) AND (Year = 2013)) OR ((Month = 03 OR Month = 02) AND Year = 2014)
```

or even

```
WHERE (Month = 03 OR Month = 02) AND (Year = 2013 OR Year = 2014)
```

?

Because `Month` can't be equal to both `02` and `03`